# Как выполнить команду в cmd через Python

Tags: python, cmd

Хотел автоматизировать отправку в репозиторий. Подскажите как можно выполнить команду в cmd через python. В частности интересует:
переход в определенный каталог, проверка на изменения в каталоге(git status), отловить ответ и в зависимости от ответа(названий файлов и изменен/новый файл) 
добавлять в commit. Хотел добавлять не все файлы разом, а определенные(сделал под это дело интерфейс). Если подскажите библиотеку для упрощения всего этого, то буду благодарен

Comment: os.system или subprocess.Popen

Comment: А не проще для этого использовать библиотеку https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?

Comment: я не ищу легких путей(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простейшее, нельзя получить вывод, возвращает только код завершения:

```py
import os
os.system(Ваша_команда)
```

Можно получить вывод:

```py
import subprocess

cmd = "date" # Здесь вместо date Ваша команда для git

returned_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd) # returned_output содержит вывод в виде строки байтов

print('Результат выполнения команды:', returned_output.decode("utf-8")) # Преобразуем байты в строку
```

Comment: спасибо большое, я что-то забыл про нее

Comment: @testgity Модифицировал ответ, посмотрите, может пригодится. И отметьте, пожалуйста, как решение, если вопросов больше не осталось

Comment: А вот если нужно переходить в другой каталог(в котором не находится проект) как быть? т.е как сохранить этот переход. Делаю следующее: dir, потом перехожу cd .. , затем делаю опять dir , ответы у обеих команд dir одинаковый

Comment: @testgity Попробуйте `dir && cd ... && dir`, где вместо `...` относительный путь перехода

Comment: все работает, спасибо большое еще раз

Comment: а если вдруг возникнет нужда не в одной команде все делать, не знаете?

Comment: @testgity Хммм, нет, так сразу не скажу. Попробуйте погуглить про `subprocess`

Comment: Ваша программа выше выводит ошибку FIleNotFoundException, подскажите с чем может быть связано?

Comment: @testgity Возможно, Вы пытаетесь сделать какие-то операции с файлами?

Comment: нет, скопировал вашу программу полностью, решил посмотреть на вывод(я новичок в python)

Comment: @testgity Секунду

Comment: @testgity Странно, я всё проверил, должно работать. попробуйте задать отдельный вопрос на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
import subprocess 

output = subprocess.run(['git', '--version'], capture_output=True, text=True)
                        
print(output.stdout)
```

Вывод:

```
git version 2.42.1
```

Comment: Это по сути тот же subprocess, что в существующем ответе. Просто немного разные варианты одного и того же. Причем вариант с subprocess.check_output проще.